# I'm trying to enter a formatted date string as "yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s +0000" mySQL from Swift 5. Instead, I get "yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s 0000". How to add "+"?

Tags: swift, dateformatter

```
@objc func datePickerDidChange(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    birthdayTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    
    let compareDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    compareDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
    let compareDate = compareDateFormatter.date(from: "2013/01/01 00:01")
    
    if datePicker.date < compareDate! {
        birthdayContinueButton.isHidden = false
    } else {
        birthdayContinueButton.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you save a Timestamp in your BDD? Would have been better. For your  date format http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns ?

Comment: I am following a course and the instructions were to enter the birthday as a VARCHAR, but your suggestion is working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> I get “yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s 0000”. How to add “+”?

Your date string in your code snippet is “2013/01/01 00:01”. There is neither “+0000” nor “0000” (nor seconds) there. So there is no `+` to add or remove.

FWIW, if you `print` a `Date` object, yes, it will print a date in the format of `2013-01-01 00:01:00 +0000`. But that’s immaterial. That’s just how `print` will display `Date` on your console. But you do not care what debugging format `print` uses. All you care about is whether the `DateFormatter` correctly parsed the date (and how a separate `DateFormatter` will prepare the date string for display in the UI).

Bottom line, do no worry about how `print` displays `Date` objects. (If anything, the fact that it is including the timezone for debugging purposes is very useful.) Just make sure your date formatters are correctly parsing/generating date strings. And, when you want to display a date string in your UI, use a separate `DateFormatter` for that (but for that formatter, do *not* use `dateFormat`, but rather use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`). For more information, compare the ”Working With User-Visible Representations of Dates and Times” and “Working With Fixed Format Date Representations” discussions in the `DateFormatter` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/).

Comment: Rob, your answer cut off. "Just make sure your date objects"... What? Make sure they get created successfully?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that sentence fragment.